# Unwanted Spacing in Two Column Unordered List

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I want to create a two column list, filling items from left to right and then downwards. The problem is I get unwanted spacing when a multiple line item comes at right side.
Notice the space at the left of 'Big Coffee'. Since 'Big Coffee' is in two lines there is too much space above 'Tea' in the left column. I want to get rid of it and stack it with just 3% margin.

How to stack the list items below on another without these extra spacing?
Below is my html sample code

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Page</title>
<style>
li{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
    margin: 3%;
    background: beige;
}
.list_container{
width:200px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="list_container">
 <h2>Sample List</h2>
  <ul >
   <li>Coffee new coffee new</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
   <li>Big Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
   <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
     </ul>

 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the screenshot[image: new ss]

Comment: by setting `margin: 3%;` you are giving a 3% margin in top, right, bottom and left. You can set top and bottom, left and right like: `margin: 3% 0;`

Comment: @cheshire The margin is used to differentiate the items. The issue is not with 3% margin. There is even more spacing. Note the spacing in red circle.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `margin` values to whatever you need, **for example**:

```
li{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
    margin: 3% 0;
    background: beige;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Page</title>
<style>
li{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
    margin: 3% 0;
    background: beige;
}
.list_container{
width:200px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="list_container">
 <h2>Sample List</h2>
  <ul >
   <li>Coffee new coffee new</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
   <li>Big Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
   <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
     </ul>

 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the problem is not with the margin value i give. It takes more spacing than the margin I've given. If the item at right side takes more height then the extra height reflects as a blank space above left item

Answer (score 0):

You should specify clearly in your property 'margin' which space do you want to get rid.

```
li{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
    margin: 3%; /* this will just create 3% equal spacing in top, right, bottom, left */
    background: beige;
}
```

**Margin Property**

> margin: [top] [right] [bottom] [left]

e.g.

```
li {
   float: left;
   width: 40%;
   display: block;
   margin: 3% 0 3% 0; /* This will create 3% margin in top and bottom and 0 in right and left */
   background: beige;
}
```

**margin:10px 5px 15px 20px;**

- top margin is 10px
- right margin is 5px
- bottom margin is 15px
- left margin is 20px

**margin:10px 5px 15px;**

- top margin is 10px
- right and left margins are 5px
- bottom margin is 15px

**margin:10px 5px;**

- top and bottom margins are 10px
- right and left margins are 5px

**margin:10px;**

- all four margins are 10px

Please refer to this [source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Cou can change `width` to `50%` and `margin` to `3% 0`.

Final CSS code is:

```
li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 3% 0;
    background: beige;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Use this jquery code in order to get rid of the particular space.

```
$('li').each(function() {
   var li = $(this).height();
   if(li > 18) {
     $(this).next("li").css({"margin-top":"0","margin-bottom":"0"});
   }
});
```